# Swift - How to convert a swift array to NSArray?

Tags: swift, casting, nsarray

I have the following class

```
class Game {
// An array of player objects
    private var playerList: [Player]?
}
```

I want to enumerate through the playerList; this requires to `import Foundation` then cast it to a `NSArray`; but its always complaining that it can't convert it

```
 func hasAchievedGoal() {
        if let list:NSArray = playerList {

        }

        for (index,element) in list.enumerate() {
            print("Item \(index): \(element)")
        }
   }
```

Errors:

`Cannot convert value of type '[Player]?' to specified type 'NSArray?'`

I've tried:

`if let list:NSArray = playerList as NSArray`

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to cast to `NSArray` to enumerate:

```
if let list = playerList {
  for (index,value) in list.enumerate() {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

As for your cast you should do it like this:

```
if let playerList = playerList,
    list = playerList as? NSArray {
  // use the NSArray list here
}
```

Comment: If I do `if let list = self.playerOrderList as? NSArray {`  it says; `Cast from '[Player]?' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails`

Comment: Yeah I forgot to unwrap the optional first, typing this on my phone and couldn't test the code. Updating the answer.

Comment: Accepted. Your answer works as expected.  Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert an optional array to NSArray, you have to first unwrap the array. You can do this via test, like this:

```
if let playerList = playerList{
    let list:NSArray = playerList
}
```